# google coral dev board mini, unable to login with serial console

Tags: putty, public-key, serial-communication, google-coral

i've bought on amazon a google coral dev board mini, i did everything i need for doing the mdt-shell, i 've created the enviroment, installed the mdt library, did mdt devices, and after the shell i had this problem:

Waiting for a device...
Connecting to zippy-tang at 192.168.101.2
Key not present on zippy-tang -- pushing

Couldn't connect to keymaster on zippy-tang: [WinError 10061] Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione.

Did you previously connect from a different machine? If so,
mdt-keymaster will not be running as it only accepts a single key.

You will need to either:

1. Remove the key from /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys on the
   device via the serial console

- or -

  2. Copy the mdt private key from your home directory on this host
     in ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key to the first machine and use
     'mdt pushkey mdt.key' to add that key to the device's
     authorized_keys file.

Failed to push via keymaster -- will attempt password login as a fallback.
Can't login using default credentials: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']

since i don't have the key on my device, i bought a usb to ttl adapter(ch341), i tried both on ubuntu and windows 10 following the documentation on the site to connect through the serial console, but, at last point of the documentation, but when i press enter, the login page doesn't shows up